# Как создать 7 виртуальных gpu в intel GVTg

Tags: gpu, intel

Хочу создать 7 виртуальных машин, чтобы каждая из них имела возможность аппаратного ускорения графики. На бумаге технология [intel GVTg](https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/release_note)
мне отлично подходит - в описании указано, что можно создать 7 виртуальных gpu (Supported total vGPU number <= 7), но есть ряд системных требований

- Intel Xeon (TM) E3 v4/v5 or Intel 5th/6th Generation Core (TM) processors with Intel Graphics processors
- Linux distribution with KVM/VFIO mediated device framework
- System memory >= 16GB (3 guest VMs), 32GB (7 guest VMs)
- Graphic aperture size >= 1GB
- Qemu version >= v2.8.0
- Kernel version >= 4.10.0-rc7+

Окей, у меня процессор Intel® Xeon® E3-1275 v6 со встроенной HD Graphics P630, 32GB оперативной памяти. Устанавливаю все по официальной инструкции [GVTg_Setup_Guide](https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide) и вижу заветный вывод команды

```
ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/
i915-GVTg_V5_4  i915-GVTg_V5_8
```

далее описание каждого из типов виртуальных gpu

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/description
low_gm_size: 64MB
high_gm_size: 384MB
fence: 4
resolution: 1024x768
weight: 2

cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_4/description
low_gm_size: 128MB
high_gm_size: 512MB
fence: 4
resolution: 1920x1200
weight: 4
```

Далее - максимальное количество виртуальных gpu каждого типа, которые можно создать

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/available_instances
2

cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_4/available_instances
1
```

Тоесть я могу создать 2 виртуальных gpu, при попытке создания 3-его получаю следующую ошибку

```
$ echo "a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9525" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/create
a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9525
$ echo "a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9526" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/create
a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9526
$ echo "a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9527" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/create
a297db4a-f4c2-11e6-90f6-d3b88d6c9527
tee: '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/mdev_supported_types/i915-GVTg_V5_8/create': No space left on device
```

No space left on device. Видимо не хватает видеопамяти - "не проблема" заходим в биос и увеличиваем. У меня в биосе есть только один параметр позволяющий хоть как-то влиять на видеопамять - "DVMT Pre-Allocated" устанавливаем максимальное возможное значение - 1024MB
[image: тут скрин биоса]

Но это не помогает, все так же максимальное возможное количество виртуальных gpu - 2

Далее выводы команд, которые, возможно, могут как-то помочь

```
lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics P630 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics P630
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
    Memory at de000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

sudo dmesg | grep drm
[    1.467196] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
[    1.467495] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.467920] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.473623] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.473625] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.476259] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    1.478841] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20171023 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.680602] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.720798] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.748451] [drm] RC6 on
```

Может кто уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Я уже как выжатый лимон - нет ни единой мыслы что еще можно сделать. На сколько я знаю интегрированная графика от интел не имеет собственной видеопамяти, а использует часть оперативной памяти. В спецификации моего процессора указано "Макс. объем видеопамяти графической системы 64 GB". На данный момент ясно точно, что моя текущая конфигурация не подходит по требованию Graphic aperture size >= 1GB
Что можно сделать для увеличения этого параметра? Кто-то вообще смог создать указанные 7 виртуальных gpu? Если да, какие комплекующие вы используете? Буду рад любому совету (Кажется, мне надо с кем-нибудь поговрить иначе нервного срыва не избежать=))

Answer (score 1):

Нужна материнка в биосе, которой есть возможность менять параметр Graphics Aperture Size >= 1024MB. Это размер адресной таблицы, производители устанавливают его в 16-128мб и этого достаточно для одной машины, но когда мы говорим об виртуализации рабочих мест, то это быстро становится узким местом. Ищите материнку, которая позволяет устанавливать этот параметр.